# Apache internal server error for Perl scripts

Tags: apache, perl, lamp

I am installing a LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, Perl) stack and I have an issue running some scripts on the web server. I have given full permissions (755) on the directories and files but still receive 500 internal server errors on some files.

See below browser console error & apache error log.

[image: error from browser console]

[image: apache error log]

apache2.conf file:

[image]

Comment: When you're asking for help, please don't post screenshots or photographs. Cut & paste the text directly into the message.

Why?
1. It's easier for people to read it.
2. It allows those reading it to cut & paste the text, making it easier to work on solving your problem.
3. It makes it searchable, so that someone can find this thread when Googling for information in the future.
4. A screen reader can't read a picture which limits access to some in our community.

Answer (score 3):

The error is specified in the picture, together with a fix. Fix the code: remove `defined` from the indicated line.

See [defined](http://p3rl.org/defined) for details.

Comment: I have not written the code myself, I am simply installing it and do not wish to edit it, does this mean I may require an older version of Perl perhaps? current version: 5.30.0

Comment: Yes, `defined` on arrays was removed in [Perl 5.22](http://p3rl.org/perl5220delta) (2015).

Comment: Using defined() on arrays was deprecated and then made a compile-time error because people mostly used it to check whether the array was non-empty, but the result it returned usually indicated whether the array had *ever* been non-empty rather than currently empty. So 99% of time removing defined() is the correct fix, but each piece of broken code needs to be examined on its merits.

Comment: You're probably looking for something like 5.8 or 5.10 because shortly afterwards those `defined @array` lines started emitting deprecation warnings.

Comment: The author of the code has had at least 15 years to fix this bug! /// It results in an compile-time error since 5.22 (2015). It warned by default (i.e. even without using `-w` or `use warnings;`) since 5.12 (2010). It warned before that (when using `-w` or `use warnings;`) as far back as I can check (5.10, 2007). [@AKHolland]

Comment: @matthewhill: Alternatively, you could contact the author of the code and ask them to supply a version that works with modern versions of Perl.